# Rest com Angular 2

Tags: c#, api, rest, restful, angular

Nestas últimas semanas venho treinando muito em angular 2. No entanto, algumas duvidas surgiram no decorrer destes meus estudos e gostaria da ajuda de vocês para quem sabe sanar tais duvidas. Vamos lá:

Pergunta #1 - Nos meus estudos venho utilizando uma API no formato DDD (Visual Studio 2015) com C# e o front utilizo o Angular 2 com Visual Studio Code. Esta é a forma mais apropriada de desenvolvimento para este tipo de cenário?

Pergunta #2 - Pessoal, já procurei muuuuuito mas não localizei nenhum material (texto ou vídeo) ensinando como efetuar o ***DEPLOY*** deste tipo de aplicação API + Front-End Angular 2. O Deploy pode ser para uma ***hospedagem compartilhada*** especifica ou outra forma viável como por exemplo azure / aws.

Desde já agradeço a boa vontade de vcs neste post.

Comment: recomendo quebrar essa pergunta dupla em 2 perguntas separadas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste momento estou juntamente com um colega a desenvolver um prototipo de uma aplicação. 
Temos dois projectos, um que é a API (REST) e outro que é o projecto em Angula JS 2. 
Também estamos a usar Visual Studio 2015 e Visual Studio Code sim, pelos vários cursos que tenho visto (PluralSight / CodeSchool) parece ser a forma mais apropriada de desenvolver nestas tecnologias.

Em relação ao ponto 2, neste momento temos o projecto de API (REST) com deploys usando TeamCity após cada checkin e para o Angular JS 2, estamos a usar ( Web Deploy ) uma das opções directamente do Visual Studio...( Na primeira vez tivemos de fazer um npm install..agora é só Publish..) Mas queremos também automatizar este processo.
Estamos a usar um só servidor com dois Sites no IIS 7.5 para hospedar as duas aplicações.

Comment: Em resumo Pedro, para este projeto vcs estão utilizado no IIS um site para a API e outro para o Front, correto?

Comment: sim, correctissimo.